# How to parse the nested below given json and explain how to fetch as i am a noob?

Tags: json, swift

I need to fetch the below given `JSON` date into an `array of dictionary` and how to use it on `tableview` cell labels.

There are two keys : 
answer and question

```
[{"question": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua?", "answer": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."}, {"question": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pharetra sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget?", "answer": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. A erat nam at lectus. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus."}]
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON.

Comment: `question`  key's value should be inside ""

Comment: Also `question` and `answer` should be contained within `{` not `[`

Comment: regarding tableView there is uncounted number of tutorials if you googled it

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
  let question, answer: String
}
```

---

```
Alamofire.request(URL(string: "<##urlStr>")!).responseData { (response) in
   guard let data = response.data else { return }


    do {
        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from: data)
        print(res)

    } catch  {
        print("Error serializing json:", error)
    }

}
```

Comment: please understand my question...i just want to know how to parse nested array

Comment: and consider i am using alamofire in the entire project

Comment: the answer parses your current json and regarding alamofire use data like edit

Answer (score -1):

Question key value should be in "" because its a string type not an integer.
Make an array of dictionary type and save the value in that array. after that use table view questionArray[indexpath.row].question